# How should a question (with answers) that has changed significantly be handled?

Tags: discussion

I have been watching the question [How do people build a Magic deck once they have a general starting point?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13910/how-do-people-build-a-magic-deck-once-they-have-a-general-starting-point) with some curiosity over the last few days.

If my memory is correct, originally the question was asking about how to decide when to stop collecting cards, and after being closed, reopened, and going through several edits is now a question about how to build a deck (a somewhat related, but pretty different question).

Two answers were posted to the original question, which now do not answer the new question, and the question itself has 17 comments (as of writing this), mostly discussing the closing, editing, and reopening of the question.

I believe the question is now fine, but all the old answers and comments are no longer relevant.

Is it ok for a user to change a question like this? 
Is there a mechanism in place to prevent this from occurring?
Should some level of moderation occur to clean up the page?

Comment: Ideally, people would refrain from answers until a question is well formed. Multiple close votes, and comments indicating problems with the question should serve as a warning. After the fact, if the question cannot be reformulated to match the answers currently given, the question and/or the answers should be deleted. I personally don't think much will be lost by deleting all the answers.

Comment: The question isn't even very good the way it is currently worded, "**How do they go about the actual construction and tuning, and determine when a deck is actually playworthy?**" This question is extremely subjective, even if we assume that the players objective is to win.

Comment: [Here's the original version of the question.](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/revisions/13910/1)

Comment: [Here's a discussion of the same thing on RPG SE, which does a lot of subjective questions about games](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/what-do-we-do-with-answers-made-obsolete-by-a-question-change).